# Error SDB connection in Jena

Tags: java, path, jena

I try to connect Jena with Oracle database using SDB but when I compile code I've got an error and I don't know what that means:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openjena.riot.RiotException:  Code: 11/LOWERCASE_PREFERRED in SCHEME: lowercase is preferred in this component

My sdb.ttl file which I use:

```
@prefix rdfs:     <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix rdf:      <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix ja:       <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
@prefix sdb:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2007/sdb#> .

<#store> rdf:type sdb:Store ;
sdb:layout         "layout2/hash" ;
sdb:connection     <#conn> ;
<#conn> rdf:type sdb:SDBConnection ;

sdb:sdbType        "oracle" ;
sdb:sdbHost        "localhost" ;
sdb:sdbName        "XE" ;       # Oracle SID
sdb:driver         "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" ;

# With OracleXE, it can be useful to use the user/password
# to give multiple stores in the same installation.
sdb:sdbUser        "m" ;
sdb:sdbPassword    "w" ;
.
```

My Jena class which uses SDB:

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Statement;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.StmtIterator;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.sdb.SDBFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.sdb.Store;


public class semantyka {

    public static void main(String [] argv)
    {
        Store store = SDBFactory.connectStore("D:\\pobrane\\SDB-1.3.4\\Store\\sdb.ttl") ;
        Model model = SDBFactory.connectDefaultModel(store) ;

        StmtIterator sIter = model.listStatements() ;
        for ( ; sIter.hasNext() ; )
        {
            Statement stmt = sIter.nextStatement() ;
            System.out.println(stmt) ;
        }
        sIter.close() ;
        store.close() ;
    }
}
```

What is wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: OK, I found answear.Instead `"D:\\pobrane\\SDB-1.3.4\\Store\\sdb.ttl"` it should be `"file:///D:\\pobrane\\SDB-1.3.4\\Store\\sdb.ttl"`

Answer (score 0):

From [Texicans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228626/texicans) comment [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625549/error-sdb-connection-in-jena#comment12249056_9625549):

Instead of

```
"D:\\pobrane\\SDB-1.3.4\\Store\\sdb.ttl"
```

it should be

```
"file:///D:\\pobrane\\SDB-1.3.4\\Store\\sdb.ttl"
```